# D3 Tip Multi-line for Long Tool-tips (auto for short)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have been using D3 Tip for about a year and really like its functionality. If you're not sure what it is, you can see D3 Tip in action [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579). Although, this question might not be 100% specific to this library.

In the past I have used it for short things, on-hover data values, names, ect. However recently I have an application that requires using a medium-length text blurb for tool-tip content. The problem is, the text is not going to the next line, it just displays a very long 1 liner.

CSS for tooltip styling:

```
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Data structure:

```
var data = [
    {
      value: .2,
      text:'This text is longer than your average tool-tip can handle. Special handling may be required for best results.'
    },
    {
      value: .3,
      text:'This text is also longer than your average tool-tip can handle. Special handling may be required for best results.'
    }
];
```

**What I tried:** I tried different display settings like `inline-block`, `block`, `width:auto`. I noticed it tends to look about right when I set the CSS to `width:200px;`, however this makes the portions of my visualization that have short tool-tips awkwardly/excessively big.

**My Question:** Is there a way to make it look natural for both short and long text tool-tips?

Caveat is there is no real clear way of knowing which should be big or small, it's kind of a data-emergent property if you will. So I need a clever style rule or other means. As I know, CSS does not support "if" logic, and I'm out of fresh ideas.

Comment: You are using D3 v3, right?

Comment: Have you tried `max-width: 200px;` ?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes

Comment: @RobertoTrani Thank you! That does seem to do what I am looking for, only concern is I only knew to set it to about 200px after the fact. If I needed something for the general case I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Usually I prefer to put a max-width that depends on the container size using a percentage. E.g. I don't want the tip to cover more than 30% of the chart, and so I put max-width: 30%. Is this what you are looking for? I think there isn't a general rule for this, because the tip size depends on the application, but some constraints on the size is usually useful in the general case.